# How to use multiple languages in a single file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am working on HTML file that has in-line JavaScript and CSS.  However, Visual Studio Code only provides IntelliSense for one language at a time: HTML IntelliSense only if I select HTML, JavaScript IntelliSense only if I set the file to be interpreted as JavaScript, etc.

I want to know, is it possible to see IntelliSense for JavaScript, CSS, and HTML at the same time instead of needing to switch between them?

Answer (score 7):

[JavaScript in HTML and CSS in HTML are supported in Visual Studio Code 1.8 (November 2016)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_javascript-language-support-in-html).  The link is to the release notes.  The feature should "just work" meaning no additional action on your part is needed to access it.

For languages beyond HTML, CSS, and Javascript, you will need to follow [VSCode Issue #1751](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1751).

Answer (score 0):

The IDE detects automatically the language that you are currently editing and shows **only** keywords of this language.

What you want isn't at this moment possible in Visual Studio or VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

VScode will do JS intellisense inline with HTML so long as your script tag has type="text/javascript" as its first attribute.  Otherwise it will only do syntax highlighting.